# I want to make accept system call as non blocking. How can i make accept system call as non blocking?

Tags: c, linux

This is the statement I am using:

```
m_stat_arr_nClient_sockfd[nIndex]= accept(nServerSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, (socklen_t *)&client_len);
```

This is a blocking call, so how can I make this non-blocking?

Comment: If you have to cast `&client_len` to a `socklen_t *`, you are doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) to set your `nServerSocket` non blocking;

```
int flags = fcntl(nServerSocket, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(nServerSocket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Once you've done that, calls to `accept()` on that socket should no longer block.

Comment: Be warned that the sockets you accept will inherit the non-blocking state. If you don't want them to be non-blocking, you'll have to clear `O_NONBLOCK` on them.